# modal con vueJS se muestra, pero no puedo hacer nada

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy creando una ventana modal con vueJS, que ya he creado en un componente anterior...

El modal, se crea perfectamente, al hacer click en el botón, se muestra, pero se queda debajo del fade y no puedo hacer click en el ni hacer nada... No se que está fallando la verdad.

Adjunto código de mi componente vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="justify-content-center offset-md-3">
                <label for="codigoAsistencia">Código de asistencia.</label>
                <input type="text" v-on:keyup="codigoAsistencia" id="codigoAsistencia" placeholder="Código" class="form-control" >
                <label for="cliente">Cliente.</label>
                <input type="text" v-on:keyup="buscarUsuario" id="nombreCliente" placeholder="Cliente" class="form-control" >
                <label for="estado">Estado.</label>

                <select @change="buscarEstado($event)" class="form-control">
                    <option value="en_proceso">En proceso</option>
                    <option value="finalizada">Finalizada</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="justify-content-center offset-md-3">
                <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha de inicio.</label>
                <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" placeholder="Fecha Inicio" class="form-control">
                <label for="fechaFin">Fecha fin.</label>
                <input type="date" v-on:change="buscarFecha" id="fechaFin" placeholder="Fecha Fin" class="form-control">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="d-flex tabla-resultado offset-md-3 mt-3">

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table" id="tablaAsistencias">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Usuario</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Tiempo empleado actuación</th>
                            <th>Actuaciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="data in datosAsistencia" :key="data.codAsistencia">

                            <td>{{data.codAsistencia}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.fecha}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.nombre}}</td>
                            
                            <td>
                                <select @change="cambiarEstado(data.codAsistencia, $event)">
                                    <option value="0" selected>{{data.estado}}</option>
                                    <option value="en_proceso">En proceso</option>
                                    <option value="finalizada">Finalizada</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>{{data.tiempoEmpleado}}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ver" @click="visualizarActuaciones(data.codAsistencia)">Actuaciones</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                   
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- modal para visualizar las actuaciones -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="ver">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span>×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- mostramos las actuaciones -->
                            <table class="table table-hover table-striped tabla-actuaciones">
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Tiempo Empleado</th>
                                <th>Bono</th>
                                <th>Tiempo Contratado </th>
                                <th>Tiempo Restante</th>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="data in datosActuaciones" :key="data.codActuacion">
                                        <td>{{ data.fecha }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ data.tiempoEmpleado }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ data.bono }}</td>
                                        <td class="tipoBono"></td>
                                        <td>{{ data.tiempoRestanteBono }}</td>
                                        <td><input type="hidden" id="asistencia" v-model="data.codAsistencia"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="iniciarActuacionConActuaciones">Iniciar Actuacion</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="detenerActuacionConActuaciones">Detener Actuacion</button>
                            </div>

                            <span id="minutosActuaciones">0</span>:<span id="segundosActuaciones">0</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>



    </div>



    
</template>


<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                datosAsistencia: [],
            };

        },

        methods: {
            
            visualizarActuaciones: function(codAsistencia){             

                let url = "/getActuaciones";
                axios
                    .post(url, { codAsistencia: codAsistencia } )
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.datosActuaciones = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
            },

            
    };
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Trauma cierto, he añadido todo el código de mi componente. Voy a reducirlo

Comment: redujiste tanto que no dejaste lo esencial... como mostras el modal? cuales son los css que importan para eso?

Comment: @gbianchi perdona pero si se ve como llamo a la ventana modal, el boton actuaciones. el modal, es un modal por defecto de bootstrap que está debajo del bloque de comentario <!-- modal para visualizar las actuaciones --> todo el css es de bottstrap

Comment: mi pregunta es.. quien activa el modal?

Comment: @gbianchi el usuario al hacer click en el botón de actuaciones

Comment: @gbianchi he añadido una imagen de mi problema, y a ver si en base a ese código, es normal ese resultado, porque en otro componente está funcionando perfectamente